# Ubuntu 20.04 Sleep at certain time

Tags: suspend

I just need my Ubuntu machine to go to sleep at 3 AM, it doesn't need to wake up at a certain time I just need it to go to sleep

Then I can WOL the machine when it's needed again

Comment: You might want to mention what is consiodered "sleep". Hibernate? Suspend?

Comment: as @JacobVlijm said, you have to explain what sleep-mode you need, then you have few solutions to do so, with at or cron, with or without conditions to go on sleep-mode.

Comment: If you use WOL to wake it, you can just turn it off at 3 AM. Why sleep?

Answer (score 0):

Create a systemd "[Realtime](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/Timers#Timer_units)" timer service. For execution you may use either `systemctl suspend` or `systemctl hibernate`

You should be aware, that your timer service should have the same name as your "real" service.
So you would need to create a timer service (e.g. nightlySleep.timer) and the executing service (in this case nightlySleep.service) which does the executing